# How to save the text selection and keep the selection highlight

Tags: highlighting, selection, transient-mark-mode

In Emacs 25 how can I save the text selection and keep the selection highlighting when using Transient Mark mode?

If I use `kill-ring-save`, the highlighting is switched off and I have to switch it on with `exchange-point-and-mark`.

Comment: The way you phrase your question is ambiguous. If you just want to keep the text *highlighted* and be able to *yank* it over and over, regardless of where point is, use the [secondary selection](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Secondary-Selection.html). See [Secondary Selection](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SecondarySelection) on Emacs Wiki.

Comment: I agree, this can be read in different ways. I meant that I just want to do a **Copy-to-Clipboard**, so that I can use the copied text *in another application*, without loosing the highlighting in Emacs.

Comment: Consider putting that info in the question itself, for clarity. Comments can be deleted at any time. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `kill-ring-save-keep-selection` defined in the following emacs-lisp snippet works like `kill-ring-save` but keeps the selection. I've bound it to <kbd>M-W</kbd> in contrast to <kbd>M-w</kbd> for `kill-ring-save`.

```el
(byte-compile
 `(defun kill-ring-save-keep-selection (&rest args)
    "Just like `kill-ring-save' with arguments ARGS but keep selection."
    ,(interactive-form 'kill-ring-save)
    (let (deactivate-mark)
      (apply 'kill-ring-save args))))

(global-set-key (kbd "M-W") #'kill-ring-save-keep-selection)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The following is based on Tobias's answer but use [Advising](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) instead:

```el
(define-advice kill-ring-save (:around (old-fun &rest args) highlight)
  "Save the text selection and keep the selection highlight."
  (let (deactivate-mark)
    (apply old-fun args)))
```

If you need to undo it, use

```el
(advice-remove 'kill-ring-save 'kill-ring-save@highlight)
```